# Add extra shop filters based on the current selection

Tags: mysql, laravel, filter, attributes

I have the following table (MySQL database, table products_attributes):

product_id|attribute_id|attribute_value_id

I have the current products IDs (filtered by a category or a search query) that I can use to filter the table; this will make sure I will build all of the available filters based on the current filtered products.

My problem is that I have to build the filters list based on the current products and be able to add some extra ones that will allow me to expand the results; those filters will come from products that have at least n-1 of the applied filters; the n filter will be the extra one.

Example:

I'm on Shoes category and filtering by color (black) and size (40); in my filters list I got now Color: Black and Size: 40 (as filtered); in this case I also have products that have the color black but the size is 42; I need the 42 to be shown in the Size filter as a viable option as this respects the n-1 rule for additional filters.

I don't know how to do this in one SQL query. The idea is too look in the table for a product_id that has at least n-1 of the selected filters as attribute_value_id; the results should be an unique collection of attributes_values_ids that contain the current filters and the extra viable ones.

**Maybe this is more useful:**

This is my filtering criteria (**attribute_id**, **attribute_value_id**): (1, 12) and (6, 268).

This means that the filters list will be made from all of the filtered products but without extra viable options. If I run this, then I will have, in this case, all the products belonging to the current category:

QUERY:

```
select * from product_attributes 
where product_id in (812,813,814,815,816,817,818,819,820,1361,1362,1465,1466,1582,1583,1784,1794,1795,1802);
```

RESULTS

```
# product_id, attribute_id, attribute_value_id
'812', '1', '12'
'812', '2', '13'
'812', '6', '139'
'813', '1', '12'
'813', '2', '13'
'813', '6', '249'
'814', '1', '12'
'814', '2', '13'
'814', '6', '268'
'815', '1', '12'
'815', '2', '13'
'815', '6', '249'
'816', '1', '12'
'816', '2', '13'
'816', '6', '249'
'817', '1', '12'
'817', '2', '13'
'817', '6', '268'
'818', '1', '12'
'818', '2', '13'
'818', '6', '249'
'819', '1', '12'
'819', '2', '277'
'819', '6', '310'
'820', '1', '12'
'820', '2', '13'
'820', '6', '93'
'1361', '1', '12'
'1361', '2', '36'
'1362', '1', '12'
'1465', '1', '12'
'1465', '2', '13'
'1465', '6', '249'
'1466', '1', '12'
'1466', '2', '13'
'1466', '6', '268'
'1582', '1', '12'
'1582', '2', '277'
'1582', '6', '139'
'1583', '1', '12'
'1583', '2', '277'
'1583', '6', '516'
'1784', '1', '12'
'1784', '2', '13'
'1784', '6', '139'
'1794', '1', '12'
'1794', '2', '13'
'1794', '6', '93'
'1802', '1', '12'
'1802', '2', '66'
'1802', '6', '93'
```

If I apply the filters (1, 12) and (6, 268) then only this products will remain: **814, 817, 1466**

What I want to get as a result:

The product with the ID of **812** has combinations of (1, 12), (2, 13), (6, 139); Because I am applying a filtering combination of (1, 12) and (6, 268) this product has the n-1 combinations of filters so the 139 should be added to the filters list as a new, viable option.

This is the code that I'm using in order to generate the SQL:

```
$wheres = [];

        foreach ($this->appliedFilters as $attributeId => $attributeValuesIds) {
            foreach ($attributeValuesIds as $attributeValueId) {
                $wheres[] = "attribute_id = {$attributeId} and attribute_value_id = {$attributeValueId}";
            }
        }

        $filteredSql = "SELECT * FROM product_attributes WHERE product_id IN (".implode(',', $this->filteredProductsIds).")";

        $filtersSql = 'SELECT * FROM product_attributes WHERE product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM product_attributes';

        $firstWhere = array_shift($wheres);

        $filtersSql .= " WHERE ({$firstWhere})";

        foreach ($wheres as $where) {
            $filtersSql .= " OR ({$where})";
        }

        $filtersSql .= ')';

        $mergedSql = "
            SELECT A.attribute_value_id, A.attribute_id FROM ({$filteredSql}) as A
            INNER JOIN ({$filtersSql}) AS B ON B.product_id = A.product_id";
echo "$filteredSql
$filtersSql
$mergedSql";
```

The SQL outputed are:

```
SELECT * FROM product_attributes WHERE product_id IN (812,813,814,815,816,817,818,819,820,1361,1362,1465,1466,1582,1583,1784,1794,1795,1802)
```

```
SELECT * FROM product_attributes WHERE product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM product_attributes WHERE (attribute_id = 1 and attribute_value_id = 12) OR (attribute_id = 2 and attribute_value_id = 277))
```

```
SELECT A.attribute_value_id, A.attribute_id FROM (SELECT * FROM product_attributes WHERE product_id IN (812,813,814,815,816,817,818,819,820,1361,1362,1465,1466,1582,1583,1784,1794,1795,1802)) as A INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_attributes WHERE product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM product_attributes WHERE (attribute_id = 1 and attribute_value_id = 12) OR (attribute_id = 2 and attribute_value_id = 277))) AS B ON B.product_id = A.product_id
```

The result of the final SQL is:

```
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'12', '1'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'13', '2'
'36', '2'
'36', '2'
'66', '2'
'66', '2'
'66', '2'
'93', '6'
'93', '6'
'93', '6'
'93', '6'
'93', '6'
'93', '6'
'93', '6'
'93', '6'
'93', '6'
'139', '6'
'139', '6'
'139', '6'
'139', '6'
'139', '6'
'139', '6'
'139', '6'
'139', '6'
'139', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'249', '6'
'268', '6'
'268', '6'
'268', '6'
'268', '6'
'268', '6'
'268', '6'
'268', '6'
'268', '6'
'268', '6'
'277', '2'
'277', '2'
'277', '2'
'277', '2'
'277', '2'
'277', '2'
'277', '2'
'277', '2'
'277', '2'
'310', '6'
'310', '6'
'310', '6'
'516', '6'
'516', '6'
'516', '6'
```

Values like 23/249 are invalid values for the products being returned. I get the extra values I need but I also get those.

Comment: Show code or it didn't happen. If the code samples are too large -> question is off topic here.

Comment: Of course the code base is too large but you don't really need it because is more about the algorithm than the implementation. It's a classic situation for a shop that has products filtering. Event if nobody can supply any SQL queries any idea or starting point would be good. The table provided is enough to get an idea about what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do in your example query is to replace the list of product id's with a sub-query.

```
SELECT *
FROM   product_attributes
WHERE  product_id IN
                      (
                      SELECT DISTINCT product_id
                      FROM            product_attributes
                      WHERE           (
                                                      attribute_id='a'
                                      AND             attribute_value_id='x')
                      OR             (
                                                      attribute_id='b'
                                      AND             attribute_value_id='y') ;
```